# What is the word(s) for fast food?

Tags: meaning, words

What is the word for fast food? Food prepared quickly. I saw the term ファストフード used, but wondered if there is a kanji term to reflect the definition. I used the katakana term in a chat and it was not understood by the reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use ファーストフード so often. Most Japanese people know what it means.
Both ファースト and ファスト can be pronounced as “ふぁあすと” although I’ve heard some pronounce ファスト as “ふぁすと”.
In Japanese, there’s no kanji term that has the same meaning. But 軽食 is close, which means light food.